# NodeJS: For each json file in directory, read file and run function in another JS file

Tags: node.js, json, fs

been trying to do something for a while but had no luck so I've found myself here.

I essentially have 2 Javascript files (**index.js** & **run.js**) as well as a folder called **tasks** that contains several json files called run-1.json, run-2.json, etc etc.

What I want to achieve is to ONLY run **index.js** in my terminal, which then for each json file in the **tasks** folder, reads that json file and grabs the email, then runs a function in **run.js** called **login** using that email...

**run-1.json, run-2.json, etc file:**

```
{
    "email":"run1@gmail.com"
}
```

**index.js file:**

```
      const taskFolder = './tasks/';
      const fsPromise = require('fs').promises;
      const fs = require('fs');

      fs.readdir(taskFolder, (err, files) => {
        files.forEach(file => {
          async function getTasks(){

            let data = await fsPromise.readFile(`${taskFolder}${file}`);
            let parsedData = JSON.parse(data);

            email = parsedData.email;

            // do something here that runs the login function in run.js using the email variable
          }
          getTasks();
        });
      });
```

**run.js file:**

```
async function login(){
  console.log(email);
}
```

So basically, if I had 5 json files in the tasks folder each with individual emails run1@gmail.com, run2@gmail.com, run3@gmail.com, run4@gmail.com, run5@gmail.com and ran index.js, the output should be:

```
run1@gmail.com
run2@gmail.com
run3@gmail.com
run4@gmail.com
run5@gmail.com
```

I hope this makes sense and thanks in advance to anyone who can help out!

Comment: I did not understand yet where you are having problems :). Is there an error? Or does your code not do what you are expecting? Maybe you can ellaborate a bit more what the actual problem is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can change you index.js file to the below code snippet
And also require the run.js file to access the login function

```
const taskFolder = './tasks/';
var run = require('./run')
var fs = require('fs')
async function getTasks(file) {
    const fsPromise = require('fs').promises;
    let data = await fs.readFileSync(`${taskFolder}${file}`);
    let parsedData = JSON.parse(data);
    email = parsedData.email;
    run.login(email)
}



fs.readdir(taskFolder, (err, files) => {
    files.forEach(getTasks);
});
```

Modify the run.js file to export the login function which can be used inside index.js file

```
function login(email){
  console.log(email);
}

module.exports ={
    login
}
```